# Filesystem is unknown for all of the partitions in grub rescue and I can't boot from a DVD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grubrescue

I installed Ubuntu to dual boot with windows a few days ago. This is my first time installing Ubuntu. I ran into a few problems and read in an article that I should uninstall Ubuntu and reinstall it later. Unfortunately, I must have made the mistake of not removing Grub and now I can't boot into Windows. I am in grub rescue mode and I don't know what to do. None of the online solutions are working for me.
I can't even boot from a DVD; when my laptop starts it goes into grub rescue mode. 
All of the other solutions that I found online assume that you can boot from a DVD/CD/USB, but in my case, I can't.
These are the commands that I entered and this is what I got:

```
grub rescue> ls
(hd0) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1)
grub rescue> ls (hd0,msdos2)
(hd0,msdos2): Filesystem is unknown
grub rescue> ls (hd0,msdos1)
(hd0,msdos1): Filesystem is unknown
grub rescue> ls (hd0)
(hd0,msdos2): Filesystem is unknown
grub rescue> ls (hd0)
(hd0): Filesystem is unknown
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Windows booting after uninstalling Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/331149/how-to-get-windows-booting-after-uninstalling-ubuntu)

Comment: My question is different because I can't boot from a CD/DVD/USB. The answers to the question you provided require you to have the ability to boot from a CD/DVD/USB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/331149/how-to-get-windows-booting-after-uninstalling-ubuntu).

I got this on the Lenovo support forums

The solution is this

Step 1:

Shut down your Laptop.

Step 2:

Find the small NOVO button on Left side of your Laptop near the Power cord Point. Press the button. The System loads Boot Options.

Step 3:Click on the CD/DVD drive Option.

- Please refer to this Document -http://download.lenovo.com/consumer/hnt/lenovo_g40_30_g50_30_bsod_solution.pdf

Comment: My question is different because I can't boot from a CD/DVD/USB. The answers to the question you provided require you to have the ability to boot from a CD.

Comment: @ReflexF.N. There must be a splash screen that shows up before grub opens up. Please reply with the name of the model and manufacturer of your computer.

Comment: My computer is a lenovo laptop. There is a splash screen; however, I can't do anything there; I tried pressing F2, F12, and Delete to try and boot from my Linux DVD, but nothing works. It freezes for a few seconds and then goes to grub rescue.

Comment: @ReflexF.N. Which model from Lenovo ?

Comment: It is: Lenovo G50-70.    I apologize for the late reply.

Comment: @adeen-s This is really a comment and not an answer, I am flagging this for deletion, you have enough rep to comment, so please use comments to request information from the OP, or use the flag button to close as a duplicate.

Comment: @markkirby answer edited to meet community guidelines. . Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @ReflexF.N. Edited my answer for your exact situation. Try it and respond

Comment: OK Edit seems fine, I can't retract a flag but mods can see you made the edit and it should be fine now.

Comment: @markkirby OPs problem is solved. Thats what matters the most here.